# How to execute a MySQL function without showing the result

Tags: mysql, function, execute

I have a UDF that can be called to proceed data like:

```
do proceed(123);
```

If I want to proceed data from a the database I run:

```
select proceed(id) from my_table;
```

but this shows the returns of the function

Is there a way to ignore the result with something like `do process(id)`?

Comment: Why would you want to use the function like that?

Comment: `select proceed(id) into @nirvana from my_table`. But you probably want to write a stored procedure instead.

Comment: So you just want to run a function once per row?

Comment: my_table is a 200M rows and for performance concerns,and for actions that can't be done in SQL, proceed is a C written UDF, not a stored function. `select proceed(id) into @nirvana from my_table` works only if my_table has 1 row

Comment: I mean why can't you just `call proceed(id)` it?

Comment: you mean `call proceed(id) from my_table`?

Comment: @Paul yes I want per row, once or multiple times like `proceed(id),proceed(id_new)`

Comment: Well you can always write a stored procedure with a curser and run the function once per row. Or you do something like in my answer. For above example it could be `max(proceed(id) + proceed(id_new))`. Or (probably more performant) `bit_and(proceed(id) & proceed(id_new))` - if the return value is INT.

Comment: I prefer your answer since it doesn't need a stored procedure to be written, and also since a cursor might cause proceed_init+proceed_deinit to be called for each row (instead of once per full table scan statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to "execute" a UDF once per row, one way would be to use the [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) combined with any aggregate function like:

```
select max(proceed(id)) into @nirvana from my_table
```